# Does TA application usually have training and interview?

Tags: teaching-assistant

First I thought every university would interview and train their TAs somehow. But I just get to know that my university doesn't have that, at least for marker and lab tutor. Is it the way the most universities do? How could they know the applicants are qualified enough? 
I am in Canada and my field is electrical engineering.

Comment: What is your field? which country? - Like in Germany, normally if you got a scholarship to TA position they will consider the first 3 months as test, then they will prolong the contract with indication of your tasks and training plan.

Comment: @Krebto I am in Canada, many graduate TAs only do the job for a single term(4 months)

Comment: Some universities and programs assume you will figure out how to be a TA on your own. Some (perhaps even most) universities also assume faculty will figure out how to teach on their own, so perhaps it isn't surprising.

Comment: I have never heard of a university in Canada in science or engineering that train their TAs. It is just assumed that you know how to do the job...

Comment: In my experience (US, biological sciences), TA training is uncommon or nonexistent, except for having prior experience teaching the same course. Interviews for TAs are more common, but certainly not required, and less likely if the TA is from the same department as the course. Depending on the size of the course, "TA meetings" may be more common where TAs meet (perhaps with the course instructor) to standardize lessons/grading, establish learning goals, etc, but I would not call this "training."

Comment: @BryanKrause How they guarantee that the applicants are qualified for TAs?

Comment: Nothing is ever guaranteed, regardless of interview style or training. They may ask for a resume or course history. Mostly, they assume if you are a graduate student in (field) you are qualified to TA a course for (field). Most TA positions also aren't entirely free of supervision: especially if it is just a grader TA position, probably the instructor is creating the answer key. The best few students in a lab course are probably qualified to tutor a typical lab.

Comment: @BryanKrause Make sense. A friend of mine, who was a marker, told me that the instructor let the TAs to do the marking scheme by their own for the assignments. I mean even the weight of each question was decided by TAs. I think that maybe a little too much rights.

Comment: You're right it's a nutty system, but that's how it is.... When you are a department administrator, I hope you will do things differently! In the meantime, you'll have to do your own training by talking to more experienced TAs. The best way to learn to be a fair and efficient grader is to work alongside an experience grader. Friday afternoon is a good target time. An experienced grader will be more likely to agree to a tandem grading session if you bring dinner.